# cannot use X (value of type func(context *gin.Context) bool) as type gin.HandlerFunc in argument to Y

Tags: go

I want to use call this func

```
func (x *Controller) GetTest(context *gin.Context) boolean {
  ...
  return true;
}
```

as an argument here

```
    converterTest.GET("/test", middleware.Auth(), x._controller.GetTest)
```

It gives me this error

> cannot use x._controller.GetTest (value of type func(context *gin.Context) bool) as type
> gin.HandlerFunc in argument to converterTest.GET

Answer (score -1):

The method signature does not match the required function signature. HandlerFunc's do not return anything. If you want to ignore the return value of the method, you can write an adapter function:

```
converterTest.GET("/test", middleware.Auth(), func(c *gin.Context) {
   x._controller.GetTest(c)
})
```